# How to select a cell that has specific text in specific column

Tags: excel, vba, range

I am looking to change my address code from:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Machine Specification").Cells(7, ActiveCell.Column).Value
```

To one that's easier to manage so I don't have to rewrite the code when I add some new row. So I am looking for a code that would look for a specific string in column "C" and use that as the row of the active column.

I am not looking to dimension any text value as I have hundreds of different lines, I literally need something like:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Machine Specification").Range("C:C").Find(What:="Lower Film Width", LookIn:=x1Values)
```

This one gives a syntax error as I'm not familiar with this syntax at this moment. What I meant by this code is to look through column "B" and find a row that has "Lower Film Width" in the cell.

Could someone share the code for that, please?

Comment: [Range.find method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find)

Comment: You could use named ranges ([Define and use names in formulas](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/define-and-use-names-in-formulas-4d0f13ac-53b7-422e-afd2-abd7ff379c64)). Give the row or cell a name and then use `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Machine Specification").Range("MyName")` to access it. • If you want to use the find method please show what you have tried so far, we don't share code as this is no free code writing service but we can assist you to fix your code if you got stuck or errors and show it in your question.

Comment: Yeah, I am not looking to dimension any text value as I have hundreds of different lines, I literally need something like:
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Machine Specification").Range("C:C").Find(What:="Lower Film Width", LookIn:=x1Values)

Comment: Please don't post code in comments it gets unreadable easily. Instead [edit] your question add the code there and explain what is wrong with your code. We need to know what your difficulties were with that code and what did not work out for you. If you got errors please tell which. See [mcve] and provide a proper example in your question. Also read the documentation (that Naresh linked) carefully as you need to specify more parameters than you did to make it reliable and not pick a random value for the paramaters you did not specify.

Comment: Done that, friend!

Comment: Please note that `x1Values` needs to be `xlValues` it is an `L` not a one. Also please read the linked documentation it cannot work properly if you only specify 2 parameters. The documentation shows a list of parameters that have to be specified because they have no default! `LookIn`, ̀`LookAt`, `SearchOrder`, and `MatchByte` need to be specified to make it work properly.

Comment: Simply use [.Find](http://www.siddharthrout.com/index.php/2018/01/05/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/) as @Naresh suggested. I have posted some examples in the link. Simply use `aCell.Row` once the value is found.

Answer (score 1):

### Get the Row of a Match (`Application.Match`)

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub GetMatchingRowOneLiner()
    MsgBox GetMatchingRow(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Machine Specification"), _
        "C", "Lower Film Width")
End Sub

Sub GetMatchingRowTEST()
    
    Const wsName As String = "Machine Specification"
    Const ColumnID As Variant = "C"
    Const Criteria As String = "Lower Film Width"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets(wsName)
       
    Dim sRow As Long
    sRow = GetMatchingRow(ws, ColumnID, Criteria)
    
    If sRow = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Not found."
    Else
        MsgBox "The row is " & sRow & "."
    End If
    
End Sub

Function GetMatchingRow( _
    ByVal ws As Worksheet, _
    ByVal ColumnID As Variant, _
    ByVal Criteria As String) _
As Long
    Dim rIndex As Variant
    rIndex = Application.Match(Criteria, ws.Columns(ColumnID), 0)
    If IsNumeric(rIndex) Then
        GetMatchingRow = rIndex
    End If
End Function
```